# Order of "order-only" prerequisites not kept in a multithreaded makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's consider this `makefile`:

```
.PHONY: flash_bin
flash_bin: | build flash

CODE_CHANGED=0

.PHONY: build
build:
    @echo "Run Build Process"
    @if [ ! -f build_process ] || [ $(CODE_CHANGED) -eq 1 ]; then \
        touch build_process; \
    fi;


flash: tmp_config_file build_process
    @echo "Flash to ESP"
    @touch flash


tmp_config_file:
    @echo "Config flashed"
    @touch $@
```

At first glance, this piece of code may not make sense, but this is only a simplified version, which illustrates the following problem:

When runing `make`, the output is as expected. At first, the `build` rule is executed. It may rebuild some code, indicated through the file `build_process`. **After that**, the `flash` rule is triggered. The code is only flashed to some devices if a configuration file has been flashed earlier (indicated through `tmp_config_file`) or if it has been rebuilt earlier (indicated through `build_process`). As you can see, this makefile only works if the `build` rule is evaluated **before** `flash`, because `flash` depends on the result of `build`.

So far, so good. Now I run **make -j8** and I get a `make: *** No rule to make target 'build_process', needed by 'flash'.  Stop.` Apparently, the order of the order-only prerequisites is not kept anymore and make does not wait until `build` has finished.

Does this mean that order-only prerequisites only work in a single threaded makefile? If so, why? Is it possible to keep the order, but to execute the individual rules in a multithreaded fashion?

**EDIT**: I know, you can force the expected behavior this way:

```
.PHONY: flash_bin
flash_bin: 
  $(MAKE) build; \
  $(MAKE) flash
```

But still I am interested why order-only cannot be used reliably in a multithreaded makefile

Comment: I think the real problem is that your `flash` target should really have `build` as a dependency as it relies on the side effects of the `build` recipe.

Comment: ...or, rename the `build` target as `build_process` (since that what it actually generates) and remove the `.PHONY` directive.

Comment: This would slightly change the behavior. The recipe of `build` has to always be executed, in order to determine whether the code has been rebuilt. If I rename the `build` target into `build_process`, then it would only once be executed.

Comment: You indicated that `build` and `flash` shall be built before `flash_bin`. You never told make that `build` shall also be build before `flash`. And you did not tell make that it is `build` that produces the `build_process` prerequisite of `flash`. Try maybe to eliminate as much as possible all these non-file targets and concentrate on real files. Hint: even very large sets of generated files can be used as prerequisites and `$(shell find ...)` or `$(wildcard ...)` can be used to create lists of files.

Comment: If you change the order of build and flash in the order-only dependency (`| build flash` -> `| flash build`), you'll get the same behavior for single threaded make.

Comment: Since `build` and `flash` are order-only prerequisites, I expect `make` to build `build` before `flash`. The reason why I am using these non-file targets is because the actual recipes synchronize devices with previously built code. The intention of these manually created files is to avoid synchronization if it is not necessary. At that point, my goal is not to simplify this code, but get confirmation for the assumption that order-only prerequisites do not work in case there is more than one thread. Any reorganization of the code yields to a slightly different behavior so far.

Comment: "Since build and flash are order-only prerequisites, I expect make to build build before flash" - that's not how they work. Order-only dependency targets are made ONLY if target does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `make` in parallel, it means that it can schedule many targets for execution at the same time. Since there is no dependency defined between targets `build` and `flash`, `make` assumes that they can both be run at the same time. It happens to work in single thread accidentally, since the `Makefile` creates a file which it does not declare, and `flash` depends on this accidentally created file.

It does not even require multithreading to make it fail, just run target `flash` without prior running `build`, e.g.:

```
$ make flash
Config flashed
make: *** No rule to make target 'build_process', needed by 'flash'.  Stop.
```

I believe you should either make `flash` depend on `build`, or rename target `build` to `build_process`.